# Strange 640 x480 white text on grey background before GRUB2 splash

Tags: grub2

See image: [image: GRUB2 Pre-Splash Screen]

On 18.04LTS, I am getting this screen which appears to be 640x48 size just before the graphical ubuntu boot screen when using 'quiet splash' in the grub command line and just this screen before the fsck message & when just using 'quiet' in the command.

It's a pretty standard GRUB configuration, originally I thought that this was coming from xorg but it seems to be happening to early on to be an xorg screen.

Has anyone seen this before or have any suggestions on tracing where it is coming from ? - this is a kiosk and this kind of screen appearing during bootup is a show-stopper for me.

Answer (score 1):

Well, been working on this all day before posting here and sure enough, 30 minutes after posting the error I think I have solved it.

**/etc/default/grub**

```
## PREVENT 640x480 WHITE TEXT ON GREY WHEN BOOTING
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

And then of course `update-grub`

So it looks like grub may be momentarily switching between graphic and text modes and is displaying this screen, but anyway have done 1/2 dozen reboots and the screen does not appear any more, so hopefully it's solved.